# How to I extract a PHAsset's Location property?

Tags: swift, location, xcode6.3, ios8.3, phasset

Xcode says that PHAsset doesn't have the 'location' member.

What's the remedy for Swift?

[image]

Comment: Did you "import Photos"?

Comment: Yes.  I did Import Photos.

Comment: I seem to run into the same issue when trying this in a playground:

`import Photos

let asset: AnyObject? = nil

if let asset = asset as? PHAsset {
    let location = asset.location
}`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you might have forgotten to import CoreLocation;

```
import Photos
import CoreLocation

let asset: AnyObject? = nil

if let asset = asset as? PHAsset {
    let location = asset.location
}
```

When I remove the CoreLocation import, I can replicate your error.

Comment: Also related (happens in Obj-C too): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581871/getting-the-location-of-a-phasset-in-swift